# Force DOI on a newline in reference list

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, doi

I'm using `biblatex` for my citations (using `xelatex`). This is the relevant code to invoke the reference list:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, doi=true, firstinits=true, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

My reference list looks like this:

[image]

Now, I would like the DOI to *always* drop to the next line. I've read some questions that also refer to the URL, but I do not mind the URL. It's only the DOI I care for, which I want to permanently force on a newline. I've tried this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{formatdoi}{\newline #1}
```

As a shot in the dark from something I saw related to the URL, but this does not work. I see some fairly large and complex possible solutions, but I feel this should be possible in a one-liner (or something short, at least). Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually `\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \newline
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```