# Force hyphenation and justified in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

I have BibTeX imported as

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

I have three entries in my bibliography, as:

```
@inproceedings{arthur2007,
 author = {Arthur, David and Vassilvitskii, Sergei},
 title = {K-means++: The Advantages of Careful Seeding},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the Eighteenth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms},
 series = {SODA '07},
 year = {2007},
 isbn = {978-0-898716-24-5},
 location = {New Orleans, Louisiana},
 pages = {1027--1035},
 numpages = {9},
 url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1283383.1283494},
 acmid = {1283494},
 publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
 address = {Philadelphia, PA, USA},
} 

@article{barshan2014,
    author = {Barshan, Billur and Y\"{u}ksek, Murat C.},
    day = {01},
    doi = {10.1093/comjnl/bxt075},
    issn = {1460-2067},
    journal = {The Computer Journal},
    keywords = {sport},
    month = nov,
    number = {11},
    pages = {1649--1667},
    posted-at = {2015-02-09 03:55:41},
    priority = {2},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    title = {{Recognizing Daily and Sports Activities in Two Open Source Machine Learning Environments Using Body-Worn Sensor Units}},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/bxt075},
    volume = {57},
    year = {2014}
}

@article{bahmani2012,
 author = {Bahmani, Bahman and Moseley, Benjamin and Vattani, Andrea and Kumar, Ravi and Vassilvitskii, Sergei},
 title = {Scalable K-means++},
 journal = {Proc. VLDB Endow.},
 issue_date = {March 2012},
 volume = {5},
 number = {7},
 month = mar,
 year = {2012},
 issn = {2150-8097},
 pages = {622--633},
 numpages = {12},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.14778/2180912.2180915},
 doi = {10.14778/2180912.2180915},
 acmid = {2180915},
 publisher = {VLDB Endowment},
}
```

which, however, render as

[image]

I would like the bibliography to be justified (as they are) and with hyphenation (see *Louisiana*). Also, is it possible to flush URLs/DOIs to newline?
I've tried `\raggedright`, but it does not suit me. I've also tried adding `babel=hyphen` in the `\usepackage` definition, with no luck.

**Update**
I was able to flush DOIs and URLs to newline thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111082/force-doi-on-a-newline-in-reference-list) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/linebreak-before-url-with-biblatex-alphabetic), respectively.

Comment: You can add hyphenation for specific words via `\hyphenation{Lou-is-i-ana}` in your tex file.  If you need more help, then we will need see the set-up of your tex file including the documentclass used etc. in the form of a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: You probably mean “justified” instead of “centered”. You also get the warning `Can't use 'location' + 'address'` for `arthur2007`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, thank you very much indeed for your insight. Works fine. However I shall say I'm rather disappointed it can't be done automatically. Sorry I didn't attach any MWEB, but the documentclass is personalised (no built-in e.g. article)
@egreg, fixed "justified" (I was thinking of the `centering` command whilst asking the question). However, I'm not experiencing any warnings

Comment: @Alessiox (La)TeX has a sophisticated hyphenation algorithm, but it errs on the side of caution and so does not provide break points in all known words.  Place names often fall outside the standard patterns, and so one sometimes has to provide a helping hand.  In many ways it is surprising how rarely one has to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add hyphenation for specific words via `\hyphenation{Lou-is-i-ana}` (or `Lou-i-si-ana`) in your tex file.  An example would be as follows, where I have used `geometry` to provide a text width causing the break and have placed your references in `mybib.bib`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[width=11.55cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\hyphenation{Lou-is-i-ana}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you prefer to keep the hyphenation exception with your bibliography source, then you can place a `@preamble` entry in the `.bib` file instead:

```
@preamble{"\hyphenation{Lou-is-i-ana}"}
```

or you can add hyphenation suggestions directly in the `.bib` entry:

```
  location =     {New Orleans, Lou\-is\-i\-ana},
```

(La)TeX has a sophisticated hyphenation algorithm, but it errs on the side of caution and so does not provide break points in all known words. Place names often fall outside the standard patterns, and so one sometimes has to provide a helping hand. In many ways it is surprising how rarely one has to this.

If your document is in US English, you could load the file `ushyphex.tex` as suggested by egreg: `\input{ushyphex}`.  This contains a list of exceptions compiled over the years, and in particular covers Louisiana as `Lou-i-si-ana`.

Comment: Glad you did summarise your comments within a proper answer. I was about to ask you the very same thing. Also thank you very much indeed for your explanation regarding the hyphenation algorithm and I must certainly agree with you on the fact that very rarely (first time for me, actually) I had to use the `\hyphenation{}` trick (usually `babel` works fine). The `@preamble` is just a massive suggestion: last thing I want is to clutter up my main script.

Comment: One can also do `\input{ushyphex}`, that loads several hundreds of hyphenation exceptions for American English; on line 1352 it has `Lou-i-si-ana`